# Queued Jobs - Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, notifications, jenkins-plugins, email-notifications

Is there a way to get email notification if there are more than x queued up jobs in Jenkins? Any plugins that can do this job?

Please let me know.

Thanks,
Jason